# How to use an "&" character in a C# button text property to display properly

Tags: c#, text, string-formatting

My C# code is:

```
        Button button;
        button = new Button();

        button.Text = "B&C";

        this.Controls.Add(button);
```

But when I run this code the button on my form displays BC (and the C is usually underlined).

I know that I can set it to B&&C to get my button text to come out as B&C but the users of my app will not know to type B&&C when they configure the text on their buttons.

They will just type B&C, or C&B, etc, which will come out as BC and CB.

How can I work around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply replace the "&" before setting the button text:

```
button.Text = text.Replace("&","&&");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply;

```
button.Text = "B && C";
```